# Python Indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I have this code and I am trying to access some files from the sample json below
I have tried to figure out why this error keeps coming but I have not been successful. What am I doing wrong? What should be the best way to fetch this data?

```py
def _get_user_map(self):
    user_map = {}
    users = self.get_users().json()
    for user in users:
        user_map[user['person']['id']] = user['person']

    return user_map
```

#### Sample json

```
[
    {
        "kind": "account_membership",
        "id": 100,
        "person": {
            "kind": "person",
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Emperor Palpatine",
            "email": "emperor@galacticrepublic.gov",
            "initials": "EP",
            "username": "palpatine"
        },
        "account_id": 100,
        "created_at": "2019-09-03T12:00:00Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-03T12:00:00Z",
        "owner": true,
        "admin": false,
        "project_creator": false
    },
    ...
]
```

#### I get the following error

```py
in _get_user_map
    user_map[user['id']['person']] = user['person']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: The line in the error message is not the same as the line in the function that you posted.

Comment: You seem to have fixed the bug when copying the code into the question. `user['id']['person']` should be `user['person']['id']`

Comment: No even when swapped it's same error

Comment: Does `self.get_users().json()` return the JSON or does it return the result of parsing the JSON? If it returns the JSON you need call `json.loads()` to parse it.

Comment: I modified this line "for user in users:" I removed users and put double quotes "for user in "":  the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `user_map[user['id']['person']] = user['person']`
because this line doesn't match your JSON structure.
You need to swap 'person' and 'id' for your line to read:
`user_map[user['person']['id']] = user['person']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I modified this line `for user in users:` I removed users and put double quotes `for user in "":` the issue got resolved

Comment: `for user in "":` is an empty loop, it doesn't do anything.